# From several cursors On one listview

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I've got a problem with putting data from 2 cursors in one listview.

I understund that it's impossible to do it with just SimpleCursorAdapter, but
I can't find method, how to do this.

> cursor1 = db.getSelect(selection1);
>
> cursor2 = db.getSelect(selection2);
>
> scAdapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item1, cursor1, from, to);
>
> scAdapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item2, cursor2, from, to);
>
> listView.setAdapter(???);

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(cwac-merge)` or even better use 1 cursor `db.getSelect(selection1 | selection2)`

Comment: rather use array adapter put your data of both cursor to ArrayList<Hashmap<String,String>> and pass to array adapter.

Comment: CursorAdapter is much better in the terms of memory usage ...

Comment: Selvin, I can't use 1 cursor because they have different layouts. I undestand how to do with with hashmap, but its better to do with Cursor. Selvin, how can i build cwac method?

Comment: Can you change the constructor of  SimpleCursorAdapter; to get a List; Instead of cursor? you can have a list and add the data which back from getSelect Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CursorAdapter (not SimpleCursorAdapter) and MergeCursor( Cursor[] cursors)

Comment: Thanx, done. But got another problem. How to put MergeCursor into ListView?

Comment: MergeCursor is a Cursor, so use it with CursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MergeCursor`. You might add fake column `type` to your selection to distinguish data in your adapter.

BUT. Google Dialer application doesn't use MergeCursor, but rather uses complex listview adapter.

Another way is to use [cwac-merge lib](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)